# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name college logo.(image_upload)

Tags: php, codeigniter

validation rule set as like below for file validation in codeigniter 3

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('CollegeLogo', 'college logo', 'callback_image_upload');
```

image_upload function

```
public function image_upload()
     {
         if($_FILES['CollegeLogo']['size'] == 0)
         {
              $this->form_validation->set_message('image_upload', "No file selected");
              return false;
         }
     }
```

but after code run give error message: **Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name college logo.(image_upload)**

OR any other solution?

Comment: **Exact Duplicate** of [How to return data from a form validation callback method in CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030079/how-to-return-data-from-a-form-validation-callback-method-in-codeigniter)

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: use file_upload library validation, don't reinvent